# DB Query related to get data from 2 tables which are not null

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

```
select FCPDD.AUDIENCE_ID,FCPD.APPLICATION_RULE_ID,FCPD.PROGRAMME_PART,FCPD.TARGET_DATE,FCPD.TIMEBAND_START_TIME,
FCPD.TIMEBAND_END_TIME,FCPD.DAY_NUMBER
FROM FPR_CHANNEL_PROCESS_DATA FCPD,FPR_CHANNEL_PROCESS_DATA_DTL FCPDD 
WHERE FCPD.CHANNEL_PROCESS_DATA_ID=FCPDD.CHANNEL_PROCESS_DATA_ID and FCPD.TARGET_DATE is not null and FCPDD.AUDIENCE_ID is not null 
and FCPD.APPLICATION_RULE_ID is not null and FCPD.PROGRAMME_PART is not null and FCPD.TIMEBAND_START_TIME is not null
and FCPD.TIMEBAND_END_TIME is not null and FCPD.DAY_NUMBER is not null
```

can we write the above query in précised form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference Link:
[Using IS NOT NULL for multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711834/using-is-not-null-for-multiple-columns)

Try this,

```
SELECT FCPDD.AUDIENCE_ID,FCPD.APPLICATION_RULE_ID,FCPD.PROGRAMME_PART,FCPD.TARGET_DATE,FCPD.TIMEBAND_START_TIME,
FCPD.TIMEBAND_END_TIME,FCPD.DAY_NUMBER
FROM FPR_CHANNEL_PROCESS_DATA FCPD,FPR_CHANNEL_PROCESS_DATA_DTL FCPDD 
WHERE FCPD.CHANNEL_PROCESS_DATA_ID=FCPDD.CHANNEL_PROCESS_DATA_ID AND 
NOT(FCPD.TARGET_DATE IS NULL 
OR FCPDD.AUDIENCE_ID IS NULL 
OR FCPD.APPLICATION_RULE_ID IS NULL 
OR FCPD.PROGRAMME_PART IS NULL 
OR FCPD.TIMEBAND_START_TIME IS NULL
OR FCPD.TIMEBAND_END_TIME IS NULL 
OR FCPD.DAY_NUMBER IS NULL )
```

Try this:

```
SELECT FCPDD.AUDIENCE_ID,FCPD.APPLICATION_RULE_ID,FCPD.PROGRAMME_PART,FCPD.TARGET_DATE,FCPD.TIMEBAND_START_TIME,
FCPD.TIMEBAND_END_TIME,FCPD.DAY_NUMBER
FROM FPR_CHANNEL_PROCESS_DATA FCPD,FPR_CHANNEL_PROCESS_DATA_DTL FCPDD 
WHERE (FCPD.CHANNEL_PROCESS_DATA_ID=FCPDD.CHANNEL_PROCESS_DATA_ID AND 
NOT(FCPD.TARGET_DATE IS NULL 
OR FCPDD.AUDIENCE_ID IS NULL 
OR FCPD.APPLICATION_RULE_ID IS NULL 
OR FCPD.PROGRAMME_PART IS NULL 
OR FCPD.TIMEBAND_START_TIME IS NULL
OR FCPD.TIMEBAND_END_TIME IS NULL 
OR FCPD.DAY_NUMBER IS NULL ))
```

Comment: Error as below:ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 9 Column: 22

Comment: remove is not null at end as added in where clause after and condition